# AWS ASG target tracking an ECS took 15 minutes to scale-in after the desired tasks of ECS is 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS on AWS which uses a capacity provider. The ASG associated with the capacity provider is responsible to scale-out and scale-in EC2 instances based on the ECS desired task count of ECS. It is worth mentioning that the desired task is managed by a lambda function and updated based on some metrics (calculate the depth of an SQS and based on that, change the desired task of ECS).

Scaling-out is happening almost immediately (without considering the provisioning and pending time) but when the desired task is set to zero in ECS (By lambda function), it takes at least 15 minutes for ASG to turn off the instances. Sinec we are using high performance EC2 types with large numbers, this scaling-in time costs a lot of money to us. I want to know is there any way to reduce this cooldown time to a minutes?

P.S: I have set the default cooldown to 120 but it didn't change anything